# github graphql making first commit after repo creation

Tags: graphql, github-api

Let's say I created a new github repository with

```
mutation AddRepository($name: String!) {
    createRepository(
        input: {
            name: $name
            visibility: PRIVATE
        }) {
            repository {
                name
                nameWithOwner
            }
        }
}
```

Now I want to make a commit and push to it. The `makeCommitOnBranch` mutation requires an existing oid for a parent commit, and an existing branch. Neither of these exist because the repo is brand new. How can I create my first commit using graphql?

I know in the v3 github API there is an auto-init field available when  creating a new repo, but I am hoping to do it all with graphql and not combine the graphql and REST apis in my app.

Comment: Can't you get the oid as a result of the mutation? You haven't specified any return object above.

Comment: The return object is the repository with name and nameWithOwner. I checked the github graphql documentation just now to see if there were any oid fields under the Repository object, and there are---but in my case the oid that is being returned is null. The oid is an identifier for a commit, and since this is a brand new repository, there have been no commits. So it returns a null value.